# How to filter "docker inspect" output so that only certain tag:value pairs are displayed?

Tags: docker, go-templates

I created a simple bridge network and attached a couple of containers to it.

If I issue `docker network inspect webservers` command, I get a lot of output and I would like to filter out most of it.

For example, I want to check an IPv4Address value of each existing container. A sample json block looks like this:

```
"Containers": {
"2868125fa1f1b97fd765f7d6bd61d1d8eff3e9cb16ea6c3d5625ce1d331932b9": {
"Name": "tomcat",
"EndpointID": "36d35901e11d4b5be5336aa90e5161eca82c3a24f3661901461f3bfed2b2a2d3",
"MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:03",
"IPv4Address": "172.20.0.3/16",
"IPv6Address": ""
},
```

So I tried to extraxt IP address info by using "`.Containers.IPv4Address`" but got "no value" as the output:

```
kamo@ubox:~$ docker inspect -f '{{ .Containers.IPv4Address }}' webservers
<no value>
kamo@ubox:~$
```

I also tried a thing with "`range`" argument:

```
docker inspect -f '{{ range .Containers.IPv4Address }} {{ .IPv4Address }} {{ end }}' webservers
```

But it produced no output whatsoever.

So how do I extract IPv4Address info by using `--format` argument?

And what if I would like to extract 2 values from each container - "Name" AND "IPv4Address"?

Comment: Is there some higher-level goal you're trying to achieve?  The container-private IP addresses only work in one pretty specific situation (on the same physical host, without an intermediate VM, running Linux) and it should be unusual to want to look them up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get it the way you are trying to do it, since you have a list of containers, you have to iterate using rangem, on list of the containers that in your network inspect output.

You can achieve it like this:
`docker network inspect webservers -f '{{ range.Containers}}{{.IPv4Address}}{{end}}'`

But if you are trying to get all IPv4Addresses of your containers , try using this command:
`docker inspect --format='{{.Name}} - {{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' $(docker ps -aq)`

Good luck :)

Comment: it works, thanks. I also was able to produce the output containing Name:IPAddress key-value pairs by issuing "docker inspect webservers --format='{{range.Containers}} {{.IPv4Address}}{{":"}}{{.Name}} {{end}}'"

Answer (score 0):

nevermind Go templates, I'll use awk instead:

```
kamo@ubox:~$ docker inspect  webservers | awk '/Containers/,/Options/'
        "Containers": {
            "2868125fa1f1b97fd765f7d6bd61d1d8eff3e9cb16ea6c3d5625ce1d331932b9": {
                "Name": "tomcat",
                "EndpointID": "36d35901e11d4b5be5336aa90e5161eca82c3a24f3661901461f3bfed2b2a2d3",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "aab8df61e3763ae4a4f8a17235a98c20eb67c0ee22526eb4d2091beed358d30b": {
                "Name": "redis",
                "EndpointID": "f64c8601a38bcba7d9446105efc6827b0c744f5954ff2cabc860fe9cabdfea7e",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
kamo@ubox:~$
```

Comment: check out my answer , it could be a better solution than using `awk`.